# react navigation navigationoptions functional component hook

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Sorry for the bad wording for the title, I have an issue with navigationOptions with react-navigation in functional component, I'm using a custom hook for my theming.
I'm wrapping the component to then use the withTheme hook.

The issue itself is that no matter what I do with navigationOptions, it doesn't change the header at all

This is my component that is having tough time:

```
HomeScreen = ({ theme }) => {
  return (
   ...
  );
};

HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Dashboard',
  headerTintColor: 'white',
  headerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  headerLeft: (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{ paddingLeft: 15 }}
      onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
    >
      <Feather name="arrow-left" size={24} color="#ffffff" />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ),
  headerRight: (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>

    </View>
  ),
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
}
});

export default withTheme(HomeScreen);
```

And the themeProvider component

```
const STORAGE_KEY = 'THEME_ID';
const ThemeContext = React.createContext();

export const ThemeContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [themeID, setThemeID] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const storedThemeID = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
      if (storedThemeID) setThemeID(storedThemeID);
      else setThemeID(THEMES[1].key);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ themeID, setThemeID }}>
      {!!themeID ? children : null}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function withTheme(Component) {
  return props => {
    const { themeID, setThemeID } = useContext(ThemeContext);

    const getTheme = themeID => THEMES.find(theme => theme.key === themeID);
    const setTheme = themeID => {
      AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, themeID);
      setThemeID(themeID);
    };

    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        themes={THEMES}
        theme={getTheme(themeID)}
        setTheme={setTheme}
      />
    );
  };
}
```

Picture of header: [image]

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Could headerLeft and headerRight be functions, to make them dynamic?

Comment: As far as I can tell the issue isn't t with headerLeft and headerRight as I tried to remove them and the header wouldnt still make any changes, removing the withTheme hook renders the correct header, but I'm not entirely sure what can be done differently in the themeProvider component.

Comment: Perhaps [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/802) may help. The v3 solution has turned `navigationOptions` into a function! (I found that by [googling around](https://www.google.de/search?q=navigationOptions+headerLeft+withTheme).)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using React Navigation 4.x or the newer 5.x?

In the newer version, you simply define the options when you declare the screen in the navigator, like in this upgrading document https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#specifying-navigationoptions-for-a-screen.

Not sure about version 4, as I personally did not using navigation options in that version.

Comment: I'm using 4x.
The issue seems to be with - withTheme hook as if I remove the withTheme, it shows the header correctly.

Comment: @MikkKüttim When you do useState in ThemeProvider, you need to provide a default value. For example, `const [theme, setTheme] = useState(null)`. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: The themeprovider is for changing background color, not the header, I'd just like to manually define the navigationOptions in the components itself, however it doesn't work that's why I said the issue is with withTheme hook but i'm not sure what's wrong with it, because bare workflow with functional components and using the same navigationOptions code work.

Edit: By bare workflow I mean minimal code.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was still using react-navigation v3 instead of v4 - after upgrading the library, the issue went away and I could've used navigationOptions in the drawer component and header popped up.